# Django adding items with JSON, error Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x97dos'

Tags: python, json, utf-8, django-models, django-views

I am trying to iterate through a JSON object and save that information into Django fields and have had pretty good success so far. However when processing data from foreign countries I am having problems ignoring special characters.

a simplified version of the code block in customers.views is below:

```
customer_list = getcustomers() #pulls standard JSON object  
if customer_list:
    for mycustomer in customer_list:
        entry = Customer(pressid=mycustomer['id'], 
                email = mycustomer['email'],
                first_name = mycustomer['first_name']
                )
```

The code above works great... until you introduce a foreign character, say a name with non-utf-8 charset.

An example error is:

```
Warning at /customers/update/
Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x97dos' for column 'first_name' at row 1
```

I have tried adding the .encode('utf-8') to the end of strings, but I still get this error, and haven't found a way to avoid it. I am okay with truncation of data in a particular field if it uses invalid characters, but I can't make a list of all possible characters because next thing you know a new customer will use a letter I didn't know existed.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you get the string to display straight up - outside of Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your databes is not configurated correctly.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/unicode/

For example table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api_projekt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazwa` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nazwa` (`nazwa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

Will raise error when you try add non-ASCII character. You need to change encoding from latin1 to utf-8.

It should look:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api_projekt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazwa` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nazwa` (`nazwa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

To fix it:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: You want to be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Assuming the database had been made correctly would Django then automatically create it's tables appropriately? Or do you need to add more to the Django models in order to ensure it is done properly?

Comment: django syncdb is creating tables without specify charset and collation. You can't set charset in models. They are determined by database charset. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings .

Comment: Regardless the fix to the collation you gave made it possible to store things without truncating data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the unicode python documents, and found a line that appears to be solving things https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html.

I added .encode('ascii', 'ignore') instead of .encode(utf-8) and it is now working on all values.

This method truncates all unknown characters, and it is the best I could come up with.